# How do I specify the timezone when inserting or updating a row with timestamp in Spring JDBC Template?

Tags: spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

In JDBC API, I can simply set UTC timezone using the following

**For inserting or updating**

```
PreparedStatement myPreparedStatement = ...
myPreparedStatement.setTimestamp( 1, myDateTime, Calendar.getInstance( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ) ));
```

**For querying**

```
ResultSet rs = ...
rs.next();
rs.getTimestamp( 1,  Calendar.getInstance( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ) ) )
```

**Using Spring JDBC Template**, I will need to use something like this to query.

For querying, I don't have any issues because ResultSet is accessible via RowMapper and use the ResultSet to pass on the Calendar instance in UTC. However, for inserting or updating, I only have the following.

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = ....
SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("current_timestamp", myDateTime )
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);
```

**Question**

Is there a way to tell the Spring JDBC template to use my specified TimeZone?

I do not prefer to use the `TimeZone.setDefault(..)` because that's going to affect our legacy modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any method of `JdbcTemplate` which takes `PreparedStatementCreator` or `PreparedStatementSetter` as a parameter and set the field's meta information on those objects.

Answer (score -1):

You do not use time zones when setting or storing a date object.  Nor should you.   Which is why Date objects have no time zone.    A date is just a point on a time line.

The time zone offset is set by the client or consuming application so it can use the correct offset for its location/requirements.  If you create an offset in the date value everything that consumes that data down stream will always have to know that date is off and will have to manually account for it.   Which grows over time to be a huge pain.

Comment: I beg to disagree. When your server is on EST timezone and your intention is to always store dates in UTC, you will need to set the timezone manually. Otherwise they will be stored in as how it appears in your timezone. E.g. 9:00 +8:00 will be stored as 9:00 instead of 1:00 which is the UTC of 9:00 +8:00. Ideally JVM should be set in UTC so we don't have to do this but in real world, you don't always get what you want.

Comment: 1.  No server should be set to EST.   The accepted practice for over 15 years for server clocks to be set to use UTC.

Comment: 2.  You are not storing your dates in UTC.   Date Objects DO NOT HAVE TIME ZONES.   Read any best practices on dates you wish.   This is a very basic concept.

Comment: 3.   If you manually offset the time in this one column from all other others, and from the system clock, every query, every application running on this server, and every consumer of this service will ALL have to know to manually adjust for this, or will be wrong.    This creates a HUGE about of work for everyone down stream going forward.

Comment: 1) I can't agree with you more but unfortunately that's not the case in the project I'm working on unless we migrate the legacy code first. 2) I'm aware of that, timezones are not stored but the JDBC does manipulate so that what appears on your JVM will look like the same as what DB stores, that's why 9:00 +8:00 gets stored as 9:00 (no timezone). I am very aware of that fact. 3) No, setting the timezone does not modify the time at all. It only tells JDBC how to store the dates. Timezone is just presentation.

Comment: 3) To elaborate, if the date I'm passing is 9:00 +8:00 and if I pass to JDBC the timezone of UTC, then JDBC will store 9:00 +800 as 1:00 (no timezone) in the DB which is the ideal and expected. If I don't do it, then it will be stored as just 9:00 (no timezone) which is totally wrong because my intention is to store all dates in UTC appearance (I know timezones don't get stored) which is 1:00.